# TYPO3 - Mask | How to extend the max length of links?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In a project I am working on I need to save rather long links in MASK.
According to the database Mask saves links ad tinytext with a max length of 255 characters.
Is it possible to somehow extend this max length?

Simply manipulating the database or mask.json helps "short" term but it will be overwritten bei mask every time a change is made.

Comment: I haven't used mask yet, but IMO it is made for the *initial* creation of CEs. If done, you can export them to a static version, which can be modified: https://docs.typo3.org/p/mask/mask/main/en-us/Introduction/Index.html#who-is-mask-for and https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask_export

Comment: I would also suggest to do it like Julian wrote. Another idea could be to file a feature request here: https://github.com/Gernott/mask/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set mask as requirement in your site_package and override the field in a custom `ext_tables.sql`.

For the next project, I strongly suggest to look into extension `mask_export` to avoid dynamic generation by mask